# How to get total no seconds from a string in time format greater than 24hrs using C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datetime

I need to get total no of sec from string in time span format greater than 24 hrs. Below is code snipped i used

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "24:55:00.00";
        double d = (int)TimeSpan.Parse(s).TotalSeconds;
        Console.WriteLine(d);            
    }
```

when i ran above getting Exception **OverflowException was unhandled** . when i use string less than 24hrs say like 23:55:05.09 . code is working fine. is it is real limitation of C# or i am missing something

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a **time span** with more than **23 hours**, **59 minutes**, **59 seconds**, **99 miliseconds** you could use this code if you want to enter time spans with over 24 hours:

```
string s = "24:55:00.00";
string hoursS = s.Split(':')[0];
double hours = int.Parse(hoursS);

double totalSeconds = hours*3600;

s = s.Substring(hoursS.Length);
s = "00" + s;
double d = (int)TimeSpan.Parse(s).TotalSeconds;

totalSeconds += d;
Console.WriteLine(totalSeconds);
```

If you would like to use over 60 minutes, seconds, miliseconds in your string as well you can improve easily add it basing on the code I provided.

Comment: what if the inputstring is `100:55:00.00`?

Comment: i think above code will yield false result for 122:02:00.00. since we hardcoded value 2 in s = s.Substring(2); better idea would be get the number of character in hoursS and use the value in above statement

Answer (score 6):

You can not use more than 23h in hours

> OverflowException  s represents a number that is less than
>   TimeSpan.MinValue or greater than TimeSpan.MaxValue.
>   -or- **At least one of the days, hours, minutes, or seconds components is outside its valid range.**

see [here at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx)

Max hours is 23, minutes 60 etc.

change your string to:

```
1:0:55:00.00
```

it will be equal to 24h55m

Answer (score 2):

To be able to parse a string representation of a time span of 24 hours and 55 minutes you have to use this string:

```
1.0:55:00.00
```

If you are unsure about the string representation used by `TimeSpan` you can perform the reverse conversion:

```
(TimeSpan.FromDays(1) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(55)).ToString()
```

This will return the string:

```
1.0:55:00
```